# Are there any references about the magical red/silver shoes in Oz the Great and Powerful?

Tags: the-wizard-of-oz, oz-the-great-and-powerful

In *[The Wonderful Wizard of Oz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Wizard_of_Oz)*, the Wicked Witch of the East is killed when the Dorothy's house falls on her. Dorothy then get the silver shoes (or red [Ruby slippers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_slippers) of the classic film) that the Wicked Witch had been wearing when she was killed.

In [*Oz the Great and Powerful*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1623205/), we learn about the origin of the Wicked Witch of the West and East. But, in this movie :

> Evanora, presumably the Wicked Witch of the East, is defeated when the emerald necklace, from which she apparently get some of her powers, was destroyed. There is no mention of any magical shoes, at least none that I were aware of.

Did I miss something, or the back story of those shoes remain unexplained. Is there a reason behind this omission?

Comment: Interesting question. Although it leads on to further examination of the relationships between the books and the movies. How consistent are they?

Comment: @ClaraOnager - they have nothing (almost) in common with each other, as far as I can tell :)

Comment: Wasn't there some copyright/trademark/some-restricted-entity-or-other issue involved, i.e. the original studio owns all rights to the concept of magical ruby slippers, so the new movie carefully omitted all mention of them?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the ruby slippers were an invention for the movie alone and are owned by the original studio (or whoever). In the book they were silver. Wikipedia claims the change was made to show off the colors in the film more.

Comment: I know it is a prequel to wizard of oz 1939 so if they did reference them the slippers would be ruby but i saw the movie and I was curious about if I missed a reference to them I remember they had a reference to scarecrow though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The movie storyline of "Oz the Great and Powerful" takes place in 1905, according to [Wikipedia's article on this movie.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_the_Great_and_Powerful#Continuity) This is supposed to be 20 years before Dorothy and the Wizard of Oz, according to the movie's timeline, so it is a different story altogether.

Now, the book was written in 1900, and the most known movie version was made in 1939. However, there was a movie made in 1925, in which Dorothy eventually becomes a princess - [The Wizard of Oz (1925)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_of_Oz_%281925_film%29). I'm guessing that Disney is rebooting off the 1925 movie with this prequel starting 20 years before Dorothy gets to Oz.

As to the Wicked Witch of the East, I'm assuming she is defeated, not deceased. Perhaps she has not yet obtained the shoes.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so because it is made by disney but is a prequel of a MGM movie which has the rights to the Ruby slippers so they didn't want to refer the shoes as silver. Also in return to oz disney bought the rights to use the ruby slippers for a sequel. So most likely disney didn't want to pay that much this time for a prequel.

Answer (score -1):

In the final scene of "Oz, the Great and Powerful," the camera pans to Glinda's feet, as she and Diggs kiss behind the curtain, revealing that Glinda is wearing silver shoes.